# Trigerring the password saving by Google when logging In

Tags: android, ionic-framework, vuejs3, capacitor, ionic5

[Google password saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfMwn.png)

I have a problem with the password saving system on my Ionic 5 / Vue.js 3 application (it will only be used on Android devices) :
The Google pop-up as in the image above is not shown at the right moment.
It sometimes doesn't show up at all, or it is triggered when I press the system "Home" or "Recent app" Android buttons.

Here is a snippet of my Login.vue component.

```html
 <form method="post" @submit.prevent="handleSubmit" autocomplete="on">
          <ion-item lines="full">
            <ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
            <ion-input name="email" v-model="email" type="email" pattern="email" required autocomplete="email"
              inputmode="email" @blur="v$.email.$touch"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item lines="full">
            <ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input name="password" v-model="password" :type="passwordType" pattern="password" required
              autocomplete="current-password" minLength="8" maxLength="16" @blur="v$.password.$touch"
              @keyup.enter="handleSubmit"></ion-input>
            <ion-button class="custom-hide" slot="end" @click="hideShowPassword()">
              <ion-icon :icon="hidePassword ? eyeOutline : eyeOffOutline"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-button class="login-button" @click="handleSubmit" 
            type="submit" :disabled="!isAllowedSubmit"
            color="primary" expand="block">
             Login
          </ion-button>

        </form>
```

I'm using the *@vuelidate/core* library for form validation.
In the handleSubmit function, I look for errors, then if there is no error, I navigate to my Home page.

```ts
async handleSubmit() {
   this.isAllowedSubmit = false;
   this.v$.$touch();
   if (this.v$.$error) {
      setTimeout(() => {
         this.isAllowedSubmit = true;
     }, 1000);
     return;
   }
   else {
      //API call, no problem here
      const tryLogin = await this.submitForm();
      if (tryLogin) {
         this.v$.$reset();
         await this.router.replace("/logged");
         await this.router.push("/modules/home");
      }
      return;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'd love for android to offer to save the password but it's not triggering at all for my ionic app.

Comment: Looks like this might be relevant https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/autofill-credentials

Comment: @Kevin no, it never worked for one of my devices, and it worked once for another one

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work, here is the solution I tried and it's working for me:

in the file: capacitor.config.ts
I added this:

```
server: {
   hostname: "yourdomain.com",
   androidScheme: "https",
},
```

Then I created the file: assetlinks.json by using the following google tool:
[Link](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator).
this file should be uploaded to your domain hosting under ".well-known"